# How to trust a Self-signed SSL on CentOS 7/8?

Tags: ssl, openssl, centos7

I am using a self-signed certificate for nginx on localhost. I am using OpenSSL latest version to do this. Here is the config file.

```
localhost.conf

[req]
default_bits       = 2048
default_keyfile    = localhost.key
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions     = req_ext
x509_extensions    = v3_ca

[req_distinguished_name]
countryName                 = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default         = US
stateOrProvinceName         = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = Rochester
localityName                = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default        = Rochester
organizationName            = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    = localhost
organizationalUnitName      = organizationalunit
organizationalUnitName_default = Development
commonName                  = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default          = localhost
commonName_max              = 64

[req_ext]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[v3_ca]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1   = localhost
DNS.2   = 127.0.0.1
```

The command I used are below:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.crt -config localhost.conf -passin pass:YourSecurePassword
```

A new localhost.pfx file is generated. Then I run the below command to make the certificate and private key.

```
sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -out localhost.pfx -inkey localhost.key -in localhost.crt
```

Now, I am using the private key and and certificate on a localhost server using nginx on CENTOS 8. When I curl into the host i.e. https://localhost, I get the following error.

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Now, I put the localhost.crt file into the `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors folder`, and run the below commands:

```
update-ca-trust enable
update-ca-trust extract
```

However, the server still give me the same error! How can I trust a self-signed SSL certificate?

Comment: You're probably missing `basicConstraints = CA:TRUE` under your `[ v3_ca ]` section. This is what the `update-ca-trust` command is looking for.
See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525601/update-ca-trust-extract-not-adding-certificates-to-ca-bundle